# WSO2 Identity Server + Rest STS Client (without ESB)

Tags: wso2, restful-authentication, claims-based-identity, wso2-identity-server

Is below possible using WSO2 IS? I have gone through different WSO2 blogs. They are nice pointer. Still I need to advised on this.

Requirement- WSO2 Identity Server + Rest STS Client (without ESB)

1. Users are managed on WSO2 Identity Server.
2. STS Client use RestFul API to call WSO2 Identity Server's STS service for a) Get Security Token b)Validate Token c)cancel Issued Token d) renew Issued Token
3. Retrieve user profile using a specific Security token.

Reference:

- https://web.cci.emory.edu/confluence/display/EmorySTS/Security+Token+Service+Client+API
- http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/07/integrating-3-legged-oauth-with-xacml.html
- http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/05/managing-users-and-roles-with-wso2.html
- http://blog.facilelogin.com/2009/05/security-token-service-with-wso2.html
- http://blog.facilelogin.com/2009/05/accessing-proxy-services-in-wso2-esb.html
- http://download.forgerock.org/downloads/openam/javadocs/9/com/sun/identity/wss/sts/TrustAuthorityClient.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STS which is based on WS-Trust is for SOAP  based services. But WSO2 Identity Server also implements another specification called Passive STS - which is wrapper of the WS-Trust functionality. PassiveSTS support in WSO2 Identity Server can be used as way to obtain a token for REST client.

Comment: Thanks a lots of lot.  This can be a light of hope for me to go ahead on my project. do we have a sample/guidance/reference on this. I am really delighted.. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no guide but now.. but I will write a blog post on this and share with you.. will take around 2 days..

Comment: Thanks Prabath, hearty appreciate for your kind attention. I would love to wait for your blog. Please share the link here too. -- Regards.

Comment: Here comes the article http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/12/configuring-wso2-identity-server-passive-sts-aspnet-client