# WSO2 Identity Server obtain SAML token for rest call

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have the two applications that both support SAML2 SSO using WSO2 Identity Server. During application bootstrap (when still no user request is processed) i need one of the applications to get information from the other using REST call. However this REST call should provide a SAML token for security purposes. I need a way to remotely get SAML2 token and use it for REST calls. I have read a post about [rest sts client without esb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990527/wso2-identity-server-rest-sts-client-without-esb/) however i can't find a sample code on how to get a SAML token for my REST calls. What is the way to obtain such SAML token? Is there sample source code?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this blog [1] get passive STS sample. But if you are using WSO2 Identity server 5.0 user interface bit different than in this blog.

[1] http://dulanja.blogspot.com/2013/09/passive-sts-java-sample-with-wso2.html